# inject non string properties as @Bean method parameter

Tags: java, spring, spring-el, spring-java-config

Using java config for bean creation I want to inject non string property as method parameter.
I added a map PropertySource that contains a List and a Map:

```
Map props = new Hashmap();
List list = new ArrayList();
list.add("myValue");
props.put("listKey",list);
Map map = new Hashmap()
map.put("key1","Value1")
props.put("mapKey",map)
environment.getPropertySources().addFirst(
                    new MapPropertySource("myPropertySource",props))
```

and My @Bean method:

```
@Configuration
class AppConfig{
    public MyBean myBean(@Value("#{myPropertySource['mapKey']}")Map map,
                         @Value("#{myPropertySource['listKey']}")List list){
         return new MyBean(list,map)
    }
}
```

this is not working and i get an exception:

```
Field or property 'myPropertySource' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext
```

any help on how to do that?
Thank you

Comment: Where did you put your `map` creation code?

Comment: when initializing the spring context. using environment.getPropertySources().get("myPropertySource").getSource()   works ok. the properties are there

Comment: How you are initializing spring context?

Comment: You are making it to complex... Just use `@Value("${mapKey}")` or simply register those props as beans and use `@Qualifier` instead.